# Consulta trazendo itens duplicados + o código do produto

Tags: sql, firebird

Olá, estou realizando uma consulta SQL no meu servidor Firebird.
Eu fiz a consulta utilizando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
select ds_produto_servico, count(ds_produto_servico) from tb_produto_servico
group by ds_produto_servico
having
count(ds_produto_servico) > 1
```

Ou seja ele está pegando todas as descrições dos produtos que estão duplicados. Porém gostaria de trazer na tela o código desses produtos duplicados. É possível ?

O campo do código é: CD_PRODUTO_SERVICO

Valeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a consulta de verificação como subquery para trazer os resultados:

```
select CD_PRODUTO_SERVICO, ds_produto_servico
from tb_produto_servico
where ds_produto_servico IN (
    select ds_produto_servico from tb_produto_servico
    group by ds_produto_servico
    having
    count(ds_produto_servico) > 1
)
```

Comment: Fechou mano. Deu certinho aqui. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

`select codigo_produto_servico
from   tb_produto_servico 
where  ds_produto_servico in (
   select ds_produto_servico
   from   tb_produto_servico
   group  by ds_produto_servico
   having count(ds_produto_servico) > 1
)`

Comment: Não deu certo. Ele trouxe somente os códigos e não mais as descrições.

Comment: Neste caso, basta acrescentar o campo ds_produto_servico no select, como na resposta do Rafael. Aliás, nossa resposta foi praticamente idêntica, eu só enviei por que não tinha visto a resposta dele (enviamos no mesmo horário).